# Return percent or minimum count of total result set

Tags: sql, sql-server

Below is a sample result set. Report requirements to include

1. 5% or minimum of 5 records for each month. whichever is greater
2. Return at least 1 record for each User
3. Include any record where IsNew or IsRequired = 1

I know I can use

```
SELECT TOP 5% *
FROM [SampleTable]
```

to get a percentage but clueless how to include requirements and what to do if 5% is less than 5 records. Apologies if this is vague. I can add more context if needed.

[SampleTable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XUI1u.png)

| RecordIdent | ReportMonth | OpenDate | User | Location | IsNew | IsRequired |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12/31/2021 | 12/5/2021 | 7 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 12/31/2021 | 12/05/2021 | 7 | 5 | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 12/31/2021 | 12/07/2021 | 12 | 5 | 0 | 1 |
| 4 | 12/31/2021 | 12/09/2021 | 12 | 5 | 0 | 0 |
| 5 | 12/31/2021 | 12/11/2021 | 7 | 5 | 1 | 0 |
| 11 | 01/31/2022 | 01/02/2022 | 25 | 5 | 0 | 0 |
| 12 | 01/31/2022 | 01/03/2022 | 7 | 5 | 1 | 1 |
| 13 | 01/31/2022 | 01/11/2022 | 7 | 5 | 0 | 1 |

Comment: Please add sample data as TEXT which we can use amending the dates to sqlserver format. Also of the 2 dates which one should be used or each month?

Comment: Please provide desired results in addition to sample data.

Comment: @P.Salmon added sample data text and the ReportMonth column is what should be used for month criteria

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might get you your desired results

```
declare @rowCount int
select @rowCount=count(*) from SOF where IsNew =1 or IsRequired = 1
If(@rowCount>100)
begin
select top(5) PERCENT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [user] order by [user]) as rowNum from SOF where IsNew = 1 or IsRequired = 1 order by rowNum
end
else
begin 
select top(5) *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [user] order by [user]) as rowNum from SOF where IsNew = 1 or IsRequired = 1 order by rowNum
end
```

Comment: Bilal - This almost works perfect but the where clause is filtering out other results I need. The expected result is to return the 5% or 5 results of the total records AND the results must include  records where IsNew or IsRequired equals 1.

Comment: It won't return other records it will return records where either IsNew is 1 or IsRequired is 1. So if you want results where both of em are 1 then use AND in where clause instead of OR between IsNew and IsRequired. Filtering is totally based on your logic and requirements and you can change it accordingly

Comment: Thanks @Bilal  I just tweaked my query to account for the where clause. I'm up and running